Building a service that offers Virtual Phone Numbers for receiving temp SMS messages
Which infrastructure providers can be used to build a service that can offer virtual phone numbers that can in turn be provided to end users to receive temporary SMS messages?
For building sites like - quacker.io OR textrapp.com OR smstome.com/country/usa ?
I tried exploring - twilio, vonage, plivo and telgorithm. But, all seem to restrict / not allow virtual numbers from receiving verification codes similar to the one's being sent to the above sites.
I am running out of all my exploration options.
Any guidance if you have experience here would be appreciated.
